# Update values in sqlite database when there are multiple with the same name

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

### I'll do my best to explain my problem.

I'm working on cs50 `C$50 Finanace` currently implementing a function called sell. The purpose of this function is to update the cash value of a specific user into the database and update his portfolio.

I'm struggling with updating the portfolio database.

This is the database query for better clarification:

> CREATE TABLE portfolio(id INTEGER, username TEXT NOT NULL, symbol TEXT NOT NULL, shares INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(id));

Let's say I've these values in it:

> id | username | symbol | shares
>
> 1 | eminem | AAPL | 20
>
> 2 | eminem | NFLX | 5
>
> 3 | eminem | AAPL | 5

And the user sells some of his stocks. I have to update the `shares`.
If it was for `NFLX` symbol it is easy. A simple query like the below is sufficient

> db.execute("UPDATE portfolio SET shares=shares - ? WHERE username=?
> AND symbol=?", int(shares), username, quote["symbol"])

However if I wanted the update the `AAPL` shares, here is where the problem arises. If I executed the above query, lets say the user sold 5 of his shares, the above query will change the `AAPL` shares in both ids `1` and `3` into 20, making the total shares of `AAPL` to 40 not 20.

Which approach should I consider? Should I group the shares based on symbol before inserting them into `portfolio` table. If so, how? or is there a query that could solve my problem?

Comment: Are you sure that it is at all correct that there are multiple rows for a symbol?

Comment: @Armali Actually the user can buy multiple stocks whenever he want. That explains why there is multiple rows for a single symbol. Plus please refer to the end of  my question, I think you didn't get it.

Comment: I also think I didn't get why not `AAPL | 20` was updated to `AAPL | 25` when the 5 additional AAPL were bought, rather than inserting another AAPL row.

Comment: @Armali If you noticed at the end of the question, I mentioned that. However, I don't know how to go with that.

Comment: If by _at the end of the question, I mentioned that_ you mean _Should I group the shares …_, I don't know what you mean by _group_. Perhaps you should show how you fill the _TABLE portfolio_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+, then use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax like this:

```
UPDATE portfolio AS p
SET shares = (p.id = t.id) * t.shares_left
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(id) id, username, symbol, shares_left 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(shares) OVER (ORDER BY id) - ? shares_left -- change ? to the number of stocks the user sold 
    FROM portfolio
    WHERE username = ? AND symbol = ?
  ) 
  WHERE shares_left >= 0
) AS t
WHERE p.username = t.username AND p.symbol = t.symbol AND p.id <= t.id;
```

The window function `SUM()` returns an incremental sum of the shares until it reaches the number of shares sold.
The `UPDATE` statement will set, in all rows with `id` less than than the first `id` that exceeds the sold stocks, the column `shares` to `0` and in the row with with `id` equal to the first `id` that exceeds the sold stocks to the difference between the incremental sum and the number of sold shares.

See a simplified [demo](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=b1862bf06da0d8269a588684324d238df68215dc2db51c4ef51a3505573d5b46).

For prior versions you can use this:

```
WITH 
  cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(id) id, username, symbol, shares_left 
    FROM (
      SELECT *, SUM(shares) OVER (ORDER BY id) - ? shares_left -- change ? to the number of stocks the user sold  
      FROM portfolio
      WHERE username = ? AND symbol = ?
    ) 
    WHERE shares_left >= 0
  )
UPDATE portfolio
SET shares = (id = (SELECT id FROM cte)) * (SELECT shares_left FROM cte) 
WHERE (username, symbol) = (SELECT username, symbol FROM cte) AND id <= (SELECT id FROM cte)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1724f4835f41613ad4452658f2320be4).

Comment: I couldn't get what is the `shares_left`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @NabilAlHussain as you can see in the demo link for 'user1' and 'symbol1' there are 3 rows with (id, shares) = (1, 15), (2, 25), (3, 35). So, the incremental sum of the shares returns (1, 15), (2, 40), (3, 75) and if the user sells 20 shares, 20 is subtracted from each value of shares and the result is: (1, -5), (2, 20), (3, 55). These values: -5, 20 and 55 are the column shares_left. Now, the min id of the row with shares_left>=0 is 2. So shares in id=1 is set to 0 and shares in id=2 is set to 20.

Comment: For some reason while running the exact same sql query, it is giving me `ERROR: near "FROM": syntax error`. Any idea?

Comment: @NabilAlHussain as I mention in my answer, the code works in SQLite version 3.33.0+. Probaby you have aprior version. Execute `SELECT sqlite_version()` to check.

Comment: That was right. My sql version is 3.31.1. Any solution for older versions?

Comment: @NabilAlHussain no. In version 3.33.0+ SQLite introduce support for this sort of join of queries in an UPDATE statement which is what you need for this requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm limited with the sqlite verion 3.31.1. Could you please help me by proposing another suitable solution?

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. I was literally frustrated and you saved me. THANKS